# How to avoid bad values in textchunk when use LocationTextExtractionStrategy from iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've been working with the iTextSharp library for years to extract text from PDF files using an extension of [`LocationTextExtractionStrategy`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs). It's give me all the words and their position.

But now, in a new PDF (generated with iText 1.4.3), I have some chunks from the same line as you can see in the image example.

```
Text: S startLocation x:122 y:110.64 z:1 endLocation  x:126.8 y:125.04 z:1
Text: e startLocation x:126.8 y:110.64 z:1 endLocation  x:131.6 y:125.04 z:1
Text: x startLocation x:131.6 y:110.64 z:1 endLocation  x:136.4 y:125.04 z:1
Text: L startLocation x:122 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:126.8 y:226.5 z:1
Text: a startLocation x:126.8 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:131.6 y:226.5 z:1
Text: s startLocation x:131.6 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:136.4 y:226.5 z:1
Text: t startLocation x:136.4 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:141.2 y:226.5 z:1
Text: n startLocation x:141.2 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:146 y:226.5 z:1
Text: a startLocation x:146 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:150.8 y:226.5 z:1
Text: m startLocation x:150.8 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:155.6 y:226.5 z:1
Text: e startLocation x:155.6 y:135.3 z:1 endLocation  x:160.4 y:226.5 z:1
```

Before generate the textchunck it give me:

```
S|distParallelStart 143.5421|distParallelEnd 158.7211| distPerpendicular 81 | orientationMagnitude 1249|orientationVector 0,3162279,  0,9486833, 0
e|distParallelStart 145.06  |distParallelEnd 160.239 | distPerpendicular 85 | orientationMagnitude 1249|orientationVector 0,3162279,  0,9486833, 0
x|distParallelStart 146.5779|distParallelEnd 161.7569| distPerpendicular 90 | orientationMagnitude 1249|orientationVector 0,3162279,  0,9486833, 0
L|distParallelStart 141.5252|distParallelEnd 232.8514| distPerpendicular 115| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
a|distParallelStart 141.7775|distParallelEnd 233.1037| distPerpendicular 120| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
s|distParallelStart 142.0297|distParallelEnd 233.356 | distPerpendicular 124| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
t|distParallelStart 142.282 |distParallelEnd 233.6083| distPerpendicular 129| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
n|distParallelStart 142.5343|distParallelEnd 233.8605| distPerpendicular 134| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
a|distParallelStart 142.7866|distParallelEnd 234.1128| distPerpendicular 139| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
m|distParallelStart 143.0389|distParallelEnd 234.3651| distPerpendicular 143| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
e|distParallelStart 143.2912|distParallelEnd 234.6174| distPerpendicular 148| orientationMagnitude 1518|orientationVector 0,05255886, 0,9986178, 0
```

The code about if two chunks are in the same line return false (because distPerpendicular are different:

```
 virtual public bool SameLine(TextChunk a){
   if (orientationMagnitude != a.orientationMagnitude) return false;
   if (distPerpendicular != a.distPerpendicular) return false;
   return true;
 }
```

distPerpendicular are calculated in TextChunk class:

```
public TextChunk(String str, Vector startLocation, Vector endLocation, float charSpaceWidth) {
    this.text = str;
    this.startLocation = startLocation;
    this.endLocation = endLocation;
    this.charSpaceWidth = charSpaceWidth;

    Vector oVector = endLocation.Subtract(startLocation);
    if (oVector.Length == 0) {
        oVector = new Vector(1, 0, 0);
    }
    orientationVector = oVector.Normalize();
    orientationMagnitude = (int)(Math.Atan2(orientationVector[Vector.I2], orientationVector[Vector.I1])*1000);

    // see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html
    // the two vectors we are crossing are in the same plane, so the result will be purely
    // in the z-axis (out of plane) direction, so we just take the I3 component of the result
    Vector origin = new Vector(0,0,1);
    distPerpendicular = (int)(startLocation.Subtract(origin)).Cross(orientationVector)[Vector.I3];

    distParallelStart = orientationVector.Dot(startLocation);
    distParallelEnd = orientationVector.Dot(endLocation);
}
```

If I do locationalResult.Sort() the chucks mixed with the other in document because the data don't look ordered. In others PDF who work have orientationVector (1,0,0). The difference are that the startLocation and endLocation don't have the same y factor. Seems something about heigth.
Someone can explain me what is wrong? How can I correct the values to obtain all characters in the same line?

[Examplepage](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkdw7hukw5yfkz4/page1.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Can you supply the PDF in question?

Comment: Indeed, the PDF in question is necessary to analyze this.

Comment: I've uploaded a page from the pdf instead of the image. I was unable to publish before the PDF.

Comment: I just applied the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` from a current iTextSharp version and everything extracted just fine. So probably your *extension of `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`* introduces an error somewhere. By the way, iTextSharp currently is hosted on github. The sourceforge repository is getting stale.

Comment: It looks like the original chunks in your strategy are exploded to individual character chunks, and this process went wrong, it does not seem to have taken page rotation into account.

Comment: Thanks for your time. LocationTextExtractionStrategy extract the text correct. There be a error in my internal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is oriented landscape and the chunk has the same X component but Y changes like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtUuw.png)
Only I have to change the X and Y coordinates to work

```
        Function GetCharacterRenderInfos() As List(Of CustomTextRenderInfo)
        Dim baseList As IList(Of TextRenderInfo) = Me.BaseInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos()
        Dim caracteres() As Char = Me.GetText().ToCharArray()
        Dim vStart As Vector = Me.BaseLine.GetStartPoint()
        Dim vEnd As Vector = Me.BaseLine.GetEndPoint()

        Dim x As Single = vStart(Vector.I1)
        Dim y As Single = vStart(Vector.I2)
        Dim z As Single = vStart(Vector.I3)

        Dim y2 As Single = vEnd(Vector.I2)
        If (x.Equals(vEnd(Vector.I1))) Then 'This case
            x = vStart(Vector.I2)
            y = 2000 - vStart(Vector.I1) 'Because the rigthmost column must be on top
            y2 = 2000 - vEnd(Vector.I1)
        End If


        If x < 0 And y > 0 Then
            x = 0
        End If
```

Maybe another solution, but this works to me. Thank you again.